# VBA: How to assign sql statements in combobox items and execute on button click?

Tags: vba, if-statement, combobox

Here's my target scenario,

1. Click radio button, if true display items in the combobox (from db)
2. Select item in combobox
3. Click OK button, run SQL statement and generate new workbook

My question is, is there a better way to assign specific sql Statement in combo items?

```
    If ComboBox1.Text = “Desktop” Then
       'query = "Select * from Desktop"
        call DesktopList
    Else If ComboBox1.Text = “Laptop” 
      'query = "Select * from Laptop"
       call LaptopList
    End If
```

Comment: Is your question how to assign or is there a better way?

Comment: If what's the better way, thanks for responding

Comment: Get the value of ComboBox1 in a variable and call that variable in a query. Something like **ComboSelectValue = ComboBox1.Text** and then you can use it in your query as **query = select * from ComboSelectValue**. let me know if this would help.

Comment: I get it now. Thank you @Sid29, I missed that one.

Comment: @martiantrello No Problem. I have made that as an answer. You can accept it if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

Get the value of **ComboBox1** in a variable and call that variable in a query.

Something like **ComboSelectValue = ComboBox1.Text**

Then then you can use it in your query as

**query = select * from ComboSelectValue**